# Show sold products report status only for paid orders in Expresso Store?

Tags: expresso-store

i wanted to know how it is possible to filter the products sold report, because we have some orders which are paid directly and some which can be paid manual and sometimes they never get paid. So our order list is filled also with some shop reminder statuses and i don't want to have that products inside the products sold report.

Is there an option that only the products get counted where the paid status is true?

Any ideas?

Best Peter

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an option to filter the report directly.

Your best option would be to export the report as CSV, and import it into Excel or another spreadsheet program, where you can filter and sort the data as necessary.

Alternatively, you could go through and manually delete orders which aren't paid within a certain timeframe. That way they wouldn't affect your report data.